# Apache WSS4J Failing to Initialize

Tags: java, apache, spring-boot, security, wss4j

I am trying to get the Apache WSS4J library working to validate a `BinarySecurityToken` in a Spring Boot webservice. We can start up the service just fine, but when we send in a SOAP request, we get the following error:

```
No message with ID "invalidSAMLsecurity" found in resource bundle "org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity"; nested exception is org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: No message with ID "invalidSAMLsecurity" found in resource bundle "org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity"
```

Now, from my understanding, this occurs when you haven't called the `WSSec.init()` method. However, the only `WSSec` class in Apache WSS4J is in the `org.apache.wss4j.stax` package, and it appears that using Maven to download WSS4J 2.2.3 does not give you access to the `stax` package.

I'm fairly certain I'm just looking in the wrong places, but the current Apache WSS4J API is for `2.3.0-SNAPSHOT`, so I'm not even sure if the version I'm using has access to those packages, and I can't seem to find the API for version 2.2.3.

I'm sure that it's just a matter of finding the right initializations, I'm just not sure where those initializations would be configured.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to validate a signed xml, using the binarySecurityToken which is present in the header - you'd need to ensure that the xml is signed using

> "WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID" = "DirectReference"

```
 List<WSSecurityEngineResult> res = engine.processSecurityHeader(signedDoc, null, null, crypto);
```

signedDoc - the SOAP envelope as Document

Use this method, to validate the signature. Also, set up an instance of Crypto like below.

> Crypto crypto = CryptoFactory.getInstance("validator.properties");

**Try the below Maven dependencies (this is out of a working example that I have)**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j-ws-security-dom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j-ws-security-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```